# MySQL Error 1264: out of range value for column

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, integer

As I `SET` cust_fax in a table in MySQL like this:

```
cust_fax integer(10) NOT NULL,
```

and then I insert value like this:

```
INSERT INTO database values ('3172978990');
```

but then it say

> `error 1264` out of value for column

And I want to know where the error is? My set? Or other?

Any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: you could check this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621530/1264-out-of-range-value-fix to solve your problem.

Comment: It's good practice to specify numbers and numbers and strings as strings. `'3172978990'` is a string, `3172978990` is a number. Btw. the `10` in `int(10)` does ***not*** define any data type constraint. It is only a client display *hint*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the 'Out of range value adjusted for column' error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786509/how-do-i-fix-the-out-of-range-value-adjusted-for-column-error)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

The value 3172978990 is greater than 2147483647 – the maximum value for `INT` – hence the error. MySQL integer types and their ranges are [listed here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

Also note that the `(10)` in `INT(10)` does not define the "size" of an integer. It specifies the [display width](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) of the column. This information is advisory only.

To fix the error, change your datatype to `VARCHAR`. Phone and Fax numbers should be stored as strings. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75105/87015).

Comment: For me, the error was caused by `AUTO_INCREMENT` somewhy becoming a huge number in a table with a small row count. So I needed `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=103;` (if there are 102  rows at the moment).

Comment: @totymedli this could make a useful answer for someone experiencing same symptoms but different problem.

Comment: I use `int` for phone numbers, because I sanitize user input by removing all non-numbers.

Comment: @Reed, I wouldn't recommend using `int` for phone numbers. If someone would input an international format as 0044.... you will loose 00. Sanitize phone number in your code before sending it to the query.

Comment: @Tipul07 You're totally right. `VARCHAR` it is, then. I dev in the u.s. & most stuff I make is local to my hometown, BUT i still should code with accessibility in mind from day one.

Comment: int is perfectly suitable if your application is only intended for local phone numbers or if you are going to add the prefix separately. But i usually use numeric formats when i expect to compute such number, but phone numbers arent mixed with other numbers, they are just read. But int is a lighter format so up to you

Answer (score 50):

You can also change the data type to bigInt and it will solve your problem, it's not a good practice to keep integers as strings unless needed. :)

```
ALTER TABLE T_PERSON MODIFY mobile_no BIGINT;
```

Comment: If the application is storing a phone number, then using strings is certainly preferred. However, thank you for the ALTER statement. It fixed my problem (plain integer overflow where I was storing file sizes using INTEGER).

Comment: This worked for me ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY tbl_column BIGINT(50) UNSIGNED NOT NULL

Comment: Upvoted! Other suggestions to convert to strings are nonsense. Integers are integers for a reason.

Comment: "@Reed I wouldn't recommend using int for phone numbers. If someone would input an international format as 0044.... you will loose 00." - Another comment on this page. I'm going with `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 15):

You are exceeding the length of **int** datatype. You can use **UNSIGNED** attribute to support that value.

**SIGNED INT** can support till **2147483647** and with **UNSIGNED INT** allows double than this. After this you still want to save data than use **CHAR** or **VARCHAR** with length 10

Answer (score 12):

### tl;dr

Make sure your `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not out of range. In that case, set a new value for it with:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=100 -- Change 100 to the desired number
```

### Explanation

`AUTO_INCREMENT` can contain a number that is bigger than the maximum value allowed by the datatype. This can happen if you filled up a table that you emptied afterward but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` stayed the same, but there might be different reasons as well. In this case a new entry's id would be out of range.

### Solution

If this is the cause of your problem, you can fix it by setting `AUTO_INCREMENT` to one bigger than the latest row's id. So if your latest row's id is 100 then:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=101
```

If you would like to check `AUTO_INCREMENT`'s current value, [use this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821543/1494454):

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'TableName';
```

Comment: cant understand the reason but this one worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Work with:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `cust_fax` `cust_fax` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just table id column name delete and new id created with autoincrement then worked successfully.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31500379)