# PDO PHP - PDOException - Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'customer_id' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, multiple-insert

I am trying to push a lot of rows (400-2500) into a table using a single 'multiple insert' query (PHP's PDO Driver).

Now I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value
>   for column 'customer_id' at row 1'

But as far as I can see, nowhere does it try to insert value `1264`, especially not in the column `customer_id`.
Also the amount of `?`s in my prepared query matches the amount of items in the array that I pass to the `execute()` call.

```
if ((!in_array(true, $this->issuesCallsErrors)) && (substr_count($this->sql, '?') === count($this->issues))) {
    var_dump(substr_count($this->sql, '?')); //int: 3600
    var_dump(count($this->issues));          //int: 3600
    echo $this->sql;
    print_r($this->issues);

    $query = DBCon::getCon()->query('TRUNCATE TABLE `issue`');
    $query = DBCon::getCon()->prepare($this->sql);
    $query->execute($this->issues);

    ...

}
```

**EDIT: Some extre info**

The max value attempted to be inserted into `customer_id` is `193`. `customer_id` is `smallint(5), unsigned` causing it to allow a max value of `65535` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: you can check [that on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284494/mysql-error-1264-out-of-range-value-for-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1264 is not a value. It is error code.
Maybe you try to insert customer_id value more then 2147483647.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to alter the table manually and change from "int" to "bigint" for the "customer_id"