# MySql error at row (number) - which row is it?

Tags: mysql, decimal, type-conversion

Highest value in column `price` is 165990.00 and lowest NULL (column has nullable options on) so i am in range.

I want change datetype (decimal 15,2 to 6,2) in my mysql table but i get this error:

> ## 1264 - Out of range value for column 'price' at row 534

How i can know **which row it is?** I if look to row with id 534 it looks ok (price = 2000.00)

### EDIT:

Ok I can order `tablo` by `price` and keep looking but what means `row 534`? How i can find **exactly that row**?

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablo` CHANGE `price` `price` DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1264: out of range value for column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284494/mysql-error-1264-out-of-range-value-for-column)

Comment: Show your query. Because maybe the "out of range" don't came from the field itself but from a calculation you are doing, using the field.

Comment: @jophab his question is not how to handle an out of range column, but how to interpret 'row 534' therefore it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it's old but let's answer it.
It is the **534th** row of your query to the database starting from 1 (i.e.: first row has index 1, **not** in the PHP or whatever file). Somewhere in your query you had a problem and it is trying to tell you where.
I truly hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check row number 534 instead of ID. A simple way is to `order by descending` of that column and you will get to know which all are exceeding the limit.

you can also try `order by length(column) descending` just to make sure its not doing an alphabetical sort or have -ve numbers.

Comment: But main question focus was how i can find exactly row where error happends.... And i was updated question - highest value is 165990.00

Comment: do row numbers start at 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

`165990.00` needs `DECIMAL(8,2)` because there are a *total* of 8 digits.

What is the min *non-NULL* value?  It might be -1234567.89, which would need `(9,2)`.

Comment: Yep :) my bad... Byt still my question is how i can in future get problematic row? Is there any way?

Comment: The column declaration must be big enough to handle any future values.  Or, you need to ALTER again to make it bigger.  For `DECIMAL`, you have a tradeoff between taking too much space versus risking "out of range".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem today, so I thought I'd share what I found.

You have to use (and increment) a counter in the query. Then you simply look for the result where the counter matches the row number you need. In my case, I needed to find row number 104,808. So I used:

```
SET @_counter = 0;
SELECT @_counter := @_counter+1 AS my_counter, T.*
FROM my_table_name T
HAVING my_counter = 104808;
```