# Queue not being processed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm running `php artisan queue:work --tries=3`  on some mail jobs but I keep getting this error in the log file:

`[2018-11-02 03:22:02] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 (SQL: update`jobs`set`reserved_at`= 1541128922,`attempts`= 256 where`id`= 767) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 22003): SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 (SQL: update`jobs`set`reserved_at`= 1541128922,`attempts`= 256 where`id`= 767) at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 22003): SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 at /var/www/html/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:144, PDOException(code: 22003): SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 at /var/www/html/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:142)
[stacktrace]`

The job is actually being created in the jobs table but it isn't being processed. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Whats this database error `SQLSTATE[22003] Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1`   Probably your field is to small to hold the data or your putting a signed INT into an Unsigned field.  Such as setting a negative value in an unsigned field.

Comment: Have you created the `failed_jobs` table as shown in the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Comment: @TravisBritz Yes I did, there are no entries in it.

Comment: Are you sure the workers are running with the `--tries=3` option, and none of the jobs have a `$tries` property greater than 255 or a `retryUntil()` method defined on the class?

Answer (score 0):

Please increase `attempts` field data value

Comment: Care to elaborate further on this?

Comment: @andromeda: Because ```attemps``` datatype value(size) is less than your input value size *OR* please check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284494/mysql-error-1264-out-of-range-value-for-column) for more details.

Comment: Please add some explanation why you think that this solves the problem, and please do so by editing the answer, not by putting a link into the comment section

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[22003] Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1

IT looks like your `attemets` field is set to `TINYINT` max of 255,  I can tell because of this bit.

```
 SQL: updatejobssetreserved_at= 1541128922,attempts= 256 whereid= 767
```

And because I know that a TinyInt can hold 255 (because I just googled it..ha ha). Its actually probably defined as `INT(1) UNSIGEND`

So you want to change that to > `TINYINT`  LIKE a NOTSOTINYINT.... :)  I mean `SMALLINT`

PS I cheated

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html