# Mysql int(11) number out of range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column which is set to `int(20)` when I try and insert a number like `622108120237`, it says it's out of range. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the 'Out of range value adjusted for column' error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786509/how-do-i-fix-the-out-of-range-value-adjusted-for-column-error)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

An **`int`**, with MySQL, is stored on 4 bytes, and, as such, can only contain values between `-2147483648` and `2147483647`.

`622108120237` is greater than `2147483647` ; so it doesn't fit into an `int` -- looks like you are going to have to use a **`bigint`**.

See the [**Datatypes - Numeric types**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) section of 

the MySQL manual, about that.

Comment: what does the 11 in int(11) mean  then ?

Comment: @Thyagi Here 11 is just display width of int coloumn

Answer (score 42):

[See the MySQL Numeric Type Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). These things are well-documented.

The range for a signed `INT` is [-2147483648, 2147483647].

Note that in the case of `INT(x)`, x is the *"display width"* and has nothing to do with the range or space requirements:

> > MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits ... *display width does not constrain [or expand] the range of values that can be stored in the column*.

Happy coding.

Comment: Wow.. I thought Int(10) means.. 4Byte * 10 = 40Bytes.. I was wrong. Is is only applies for INT? How about the other types?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value you can store in an signed integer is 2147483647
And unsigned int is 4294967295 in Both case you exceed the limit