# mysql: issue with the Maximum Value for int type

Tags: mysql

I created two fields `text(varchar)`, `number(int)` using mysql. But I am not sure what size i should put for `varchar()`, `int()` , for `varchar()`, I checked here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html, and know if I put `varchar(4)`, it means: can hold up to 4 characters. But for `int(4)`, I checked here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html, It is said: `Maximum Value:(Signed/Unsigned)(2147483647/4294967295)`

Question:

for `int(4)`, how did it get this value`2147483647/4294967295`?  if i put `int(8)`, what would the value be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the MySQL Numeric Type Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). These things are well-documented.

> > The range for a signed `INT` is [-2147483648, 2147483647].
> >
> > Note that in the case of `INT(x)`, x is the *"display width"* and has nothing to do with the range or space requirements:
> >
> > MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits ... *display width does not constrain [or expand] the range of values that can be stored in the column*.

[Mysql int(11) number out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921613/mysql-int11-number-out-of-range)

Comment: Use BIGINT for 64-bit values. User strings and custom conversion for arbitrary precision/size.

Answer (score 1):

`int(4)` an INT with a display width of four digits.

`int(8)` an INT with a display width of eight digits.

`Minimum Value/Maximum Value` are the same for an `int` type which use 4 bytes to storage.

`-2147483648` to `2147483647` for signed, and `0` to `4294967296` for unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the browser console I note:

`Math.pow(2, 4*8)` is `4294967296` and half that is `2147483648`

those are 1 off the maximum (unsigned/signed) integer that can be stored in binary form using 4 8-bit bytes.