# Using VARCHAR in Mysql

Tags: mysql, storage, using, varchar

Can I use VARCHAR to store this `GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001`?

```
CREATE TABLE clients 
(
    client_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    name VARCHAR (50),
    phone_no INT (11),
    plan_no VARCHAR (20),
    job_remark VARCHAR (12),
    quater INT,
    year DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);

INSERT INTO clients (name, phone_no, plan_no, job_remark, quater, year,) 
VALUES (name= 'UAE GEO', phone_no= 07037695328, plan_no= 'GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001', job_remark= 'revalidation', quater= 1, year= '2017-03-28');
```

I'm getting an error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('UAE GEO', 07037695328, 'GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001', 'revalidation', 1, '20' at line 1

Comment: That's most likely because of the last, unnecessary comma in the `INSERT INTO`  clause - after the `year`, just before the closing `)`....

Comment: If You declare your columns you don't need asiggn it again

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your insert statement. You don't need to provide the column names inside the `Values ()` section. Also you have an extra trailing `,` in the columns section.
The statement below should work:

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, phone_no, plan_no, job_remark, quater, year) VALUES ( 'UAE GEO',  07037695328, 'GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001', 'revalidation', 1, '2017-03-28')
```

**EDIT**

As the phone number column will throw a `Out of range` error because of reasons you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921613/mysql-int11-number-out-of-range). You can instead use the phone_no also as a VARCHAR to fix that.

```
CREATE TABLE clients 
(
    client_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    name VARCHAR (50),
    phone_no VARCHAR (11),
    plan_no VARCHAR (20),
    job_remark VARCHAR (12),
    quater INT,
    year DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);
```

Please read the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) for this MySQL statement

Comment: ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE: Out of range value for column 'phone_no' at row 1

Comment: Yes, that INT value is OUT of Range for MySQL. You can see the link in the EDIT for the explanation for that error.

Comment: Meanwhile, the `(11)` on `INT` means nothing.